# Iron router RouteController gives a not defined error

Tags: meteor, iron-router

This works fine:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/about', function () {
    this.render('aboutView');
});
```

However, this gives an error (RouteController 'HomeController' not defined):

```
var HomeController, MainController;
HomeController = RouteController.extend({
    action: function() {
        this.render('home', {
     });
   }
});

MainController = RouteController.extend({
   action: function () {
     this.render('aboutView', {
     });
   }
});
Router.route('/', {name: 'home', controller: 'HomeController'});
Router.route('/about', {name: 'about', controller: 'MainController'});
```

I've tried various permutations (taken from the IronRouter documentation) but there is still the same error. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove this line :

```
var HomeController, MainController;
```

To make these global variables.

Or remove the quotes when specifying controllers :

```
Router.route('/', {name: 'home', controller: HomeController});
Router.route('/about', {name: 'about', controller: MainController});
```

Why is that so ?

When you define controllers with `iron:router` you can use 2 different syntax, using a variable identifier of a string.

If you use a variable identifier, the controller has to be declared as a local (file-scoped) variable using the `var` keyword.

However if you use a string, the controller will get looked as a global variable (a property of the window object), and global variables in Meteor are defined without the `var` keyword.

Usually you will define your controllers in different files (that's the point of controllers, externalizing routing logic) so it is more common to use the string syntax.

Comment: Thanks, removing the quotes was the solution, if it's ok to create the controller locally. I can't get it to work with the controller as a global variable.

Comment: Can you post your code with the global variable setup ? This is usually the preferred way of declaring controllers.

Comment: In the original code I had "use strict" at the top of the file to please jshint. I hadn't thought that would effect enything else, but when I removed this line, then Meteor does not have a problem with using a string to identify the controller. I'm not sure of why, but I do know that Meteor has a strange relationship with strict mode.

Comment: In the official documentation, there are several occurrences of a "controller: " with a value in quotes. I was also struggling with these misleading examples.